# How to replace an integer with .replace()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a counter:

```
count = []

def count_up(digit_1, digit_2, digit_3, digit_4, digit_5, digit_6,     digit_7):
    if(tick = True):
        count = []
        digit_1 = digit_1 + 1
        if(digit_1 == 27):
            digit_1 = 0
            digit_2 += 1
            if(digit_2 == 27):
                digit_2 = 0
                digit_3 += 1
                if(digit_3 == 27):
                    digit_3 = 0
                    digit_4 += 1
                    if(digit_4 == 26):
                        digit_4 = 0
                        digit_5 += 1
                        if(digit_5 == 26):
                            digit_5 = 0

    count.append(digit_1)
    count.append(digit_2)
    count.append(digit_3)
    count.append(digit_4)
    count.append(digit_5)
    print count
    count = []
```

and I want to change each digit in the list to the corresponding letter (1 = a, 26 = z)

I have tried .replace() but it comes up with:

> File "/Users/Johnpaulbeer/pythonpractice/test.py", line 99, in >count_decoder
>      count = [w.replace(1, 'a') for w in count]
>   AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

What else can I do, or if not then how do I change the integer into a string?

Comment: Why are you trying to simulate a `dict()` with a `list()`?

Comment: Have you tried the [map](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as, "given a list of numbers between 1 and 26, how do I get a list of characters between a and z?". You could do:

```
count = [chr(w + ord("a") - 1) for w in count]
```

Example:

```
>>> count = [8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4]
>>> count = [chr(w + ord("a") - 1) for w in count]
>>> count
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```